# testing nodejs aws lambdas locally with dynamodb

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, aws-lambda, dynamo-local

Context: `serverless framework`, `lambda`, `nodejs`, `dynamodb-local`, `serverless-mocha-plugin`.

I want to launch the local tests in one command. In order to achieve that, I thought about making a `run-tests` shell script. But I guess I am not doing it the right way.

When manually launching the tests, in 2 consoles I launch dynamodb local:

```
sls dynamodb start
```

then, when ready, in the other console, I run the test:

```
sls invoke test -f loadDepartmentsOfFrance
```

Given that `sls dynamodb start` is asynchronous and it may take more or less time, **is it possible to group these commands in one shell scripts?**

I was trying

```
sls dynamodb start &
sls invoke test -f loadDepartmentsOfFrance
```

but the second command has not wait for the first to properly launch. Without the `&`, the second command is never reached.

Even if I didn't got there, how may I stop `dynamodb local` in the same script? *There is no `sls dynamodb stop` command.*

Feel free to suggest other approaches for local testing of lambdas using dynamodb, S3, endpoints and sqs services.

Comment: just wonder if you have got a solution about this.

Comment: I gave up this approach. I guess a solution may be now to use dynamodb-local in a **docker**. `docker start .... & sls invoke test ....` ?? **Note:** I didn't try it, it's been a while since I've last used dynamodb-local. Good luck!